# How to load, scroll and pinch and zoom *.svg image in iOS device using Objective -C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, svg, cgpath

In my ios application, I am  displaying a `*.svg` file as below:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"svg"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[_webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[_webView loadRequest:req];
```

This works fine as I can load pinch and zoom the file on device. But now I need to highlight and area of image (say a room of a building or well of a garden). How can I achieve this? I have tried `SVG Kit`, but I was not able to find the touch-highlight area property. I've also used `FSInteractiveMapView`. But is does not allow me to pinch and zoom or scrol through the svg image. Please help me.